# Get request in express is not working for query strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this code is not working when I try to get year and month as typing in url
`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/2018/4`

it gives me e output as
`Cannot GET /api/posts/2018/4`

the javascript code is below

```
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hellllo worls");
});

app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
    res.send([1, 2, 3]);
});

app.get("api/courses/:id", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query);
});

app.get("api/posts/:year/:month", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

**I get output as** [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3YzG.png)

Comment: You image doesnt show a query string. Please add the query string you try to this example. External images are no good.

Comment: I input query string in url. it is '2017/3'

Comment: Thats not a query string. query string is like this `/myroute?q1=foo&q2=bar`. Please add your *query string* attempt to your question.

Comment: I have found the solution . I have missed  ```/ ```  before **api** ```app.get("api/posts/:year/:month", (req, res)```

Comment: replace `api/posts/:year/:month` with `/api/posts/:year/:month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase for those wondering why the first "/" was needed in the url for the GET request and probably tried it on their end and its not working

it depends on how you structure your routes

in this case the http url in your server.js does not have a "/" at the end i suppose that why you needed it in the routes file

example: localhost:3000 and not localhost:3000/

if you are using express-router

for example, i have in my index.js (for routes)

app.use('/api/user/', user);

i might not need to add the extra slash in the routes

router.get('posts/:year/:month);

Answer (score 1):

When you use the url: http://localhost:3000/api/posts/2018/4

Here 2018 and 4 are route parametes not query parametes.
To access route params you can use:

```
app.get("/api/posts/:year/:month", (req, res) => {
res.send(req.params);
});
```

If you want access the data as query params, then the url must be: http://localhost:3000/api/posts?year=2018&month=4
and the code for route can be as simple as:

```
app.get("/api/posts", (req, res) => {
res.send(req.query);
});
```

Comment: Sir you have missed ```/ ```  before **api** ```app.get("api/posts", (req, res) => {```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. But I hope you understood the difference between query params and route params :).